# SQS Message stays inflight

Tags: amazon-sqs

I am using sqs for processing messages. My visibility timeout is 2 min. But I have noticed that some messages is in inflight state even my consumer process that message. 
I am not able to understand this why some messages is in inflight state? 
How I delete that messages?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the message is being repeatedly downloaded by the application. Another possibility is that someone is viewing your queue items in AWS console (it tells you, "Messages displayed in the console will not be available to other applications until the console stops polling for messages.")

When you download the message from SQS, one of its properties is a receipt handle. You use that to delete the message, and it will work even if the message is in flight.

```
using (AmazonSQSClient client = new AmazonSQSClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest1))
{
    ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest(QueueUrl)
    {
        MaxNumberOfMessages = 10,
        WaitTimeSeconds = 20,
        AttributeNames = new List<string> { "All" },
    };
    ReceiveMessageResponse response = client.ReceiveMessage(request);

    foreach (Message message in response.Messages)
    {
        // do processing

        // assuming success
        DeleteMessageRequest request2 = new DeleteMessageRequest
        {
            QueueUrl = QueueUrl,
            ReceiptHandle = message.ReceiptHandle,
        });
        client.DeleteMessage(request2);
    }
}
```